# Act on Behalf of different user / XrmServiceContext.CallerID

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, claims-based-identity, dynamics-crm-2013

I have created a `XrmServiceContext` using svcutil.exe for my CRM 2013 database, this is working great and I can retrieve data from CRM in my MVC4 application.

My website is running SSO using ADFS2 and I can retrieve the accessing users identity using:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.IClaimsIdentity ci =  Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.IClaimsIdentity;

var accountNameClaim = ci.Claims.Where(x => x.ClaimType.ToLower().EndsWith("windowsaccountname")).FirstOrDefault();
```

this gives me something along the lines of

`string accountNameClaim  = "firstname.lastname@domain.com"`

Using this I can retrieve the user form CRM 2013 `XrmServiceContext`

```
var user = _serviceContext.SystemUserSet
                                        .Where( x=> x.DomainName == accountNameClaim)
                                        .Select(s => new UserInformationProxy()
                                          {
                                              Id = s.Id, // this is probably needed for impersonation
                                              FullName = s.FullName, 
                                              DomainName = s.DomainName
                                           })
                                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now I'm wondering how I act as / impersonate this user for all my subsequent queries to CRM using my XRMServiceContext.

This page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309629.aspx has a guide which suggests I need to set a variable called `CallerID` in `OrganizationServiceContext` which I'm guessing is contained somewhere inside my `XRMServiceContext`.. But I cannot find it.

Comment: Did you end up finding out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `CallerId` property  is not on the `OrganizationServiceContext` but on the `OrganizationServiceProxy` that is *used* by the context:

When you are constructing the context, you are passing in an organization service intance. Prior to that, you need to set the `CallerId`:

```
organizationService.CallerId = user.Id;
var _serviceContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(organizationService);
```

Please note that the `CallerId` is only available on the `OrganizationServiceProxy` type, not on the interface `IOrganiaztionService`. I can't see how you obtain the organization service, but make sure it's an OrganizationServiceProxy.